# Replace Library's class with my own

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a 3rd party library, what I had to integrate into my project. The integration is complete, I can call and use the library as needed. Nevertheless business figured out, it would be amazing to make some custom changes on UI.

There is one class (extending RelativeLayout) inside the library which responsible for all UI event. After checking the code, I realized I need to modify that class only.

As far as I understand I have two solutions:

- Extend/Overwrite every related class and kinda a reimplement the library UI
- Somehow trick the system and allow to use my custom RelativeLayout, instead of the library's.

When I copy the custom layout class within the same package, I got an error:

> Duplicate class found
>   I can't build the project, since the Studio says I have two classes with the same package.classname.

Do you know any way as I can trick the system to use my own class, without implementing/extending the related components?

Comment: If this is an open source library, fork it, modifying this one class, then use your fork.

Comment: Does the Library not let you inject your own class?

Comment: @Deev , what do you mean? Could you please explain this? I have the library integrated with aar files and as a module. I think I can modify the module itself. I am not sure that's a good practice.

Comment: Typically libraries let you create your own custom implementation of a class that follows an interface of some kind.  Then you pass it off to the library and it goes on it's merry way. Or there's configuration options that let you change the default. If not, then I would suggest what CommonsWare said and fork it if you can.  If not, then you're pretty much forced to drop the library.

Comment: @DeeV Or make some licensing deal with the vendor to get access to the source.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, that's a good idea. I think this is what happened, since I have access to some level of code. The only question remained since I have it integrated as a module into my android project, shall I modify the module's code or is it a bad practice?

Comment: Are you starting some activity provided by the library that uses the layout you want to change?  Maybe you could extend the activity instead of the layout and start your version instead.  You could find and manipulate views at runtime instead of changing the XML.

Comment: @Karoly Now I'm confused about what you mean.  Layouts don't provide activities, and layouts aren't started.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, Sorry, typo: yes, exactly. I am starting an Activity, which launches a kinda layoutManager class, which uses a state machine to detect what to display. This class fires the custom relativeLayout class, what I have to modify. Thanks for your help guys! Do appreaciate